# Prove that $ \operatorname{det}(A-tI) = \operatorname{det}(A-tI)^T = \operatorname{det}(A^T-tI)$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In a question I'm trying to solve I wrote this statement. My instructor verifies that it is correct but says he'll demand that I prove the statement in the exam. Can anybody point me in the direction?

Comment: Well, $(A-tI)^{\mathrm{T}} = A^{\mathrm{T}}-tI$, so the second equality should be obvious. All that is left is the first one, which follows from the fact that $\det(M) = \det(M^{\mathrm{T}})$ for any square matrix $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following definition of the determinant:
$$\det(A):=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}\varepsilon(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^na_{i,\sigma(i)},$$
where $A=(a_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$, $\mathfrak{S}_n$ is the permutation group on $n$ letters and $\varepsilon$ the signature.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer! However, this is kind of too advanced for me. Can I mutate my question a little bit in this way: My initial question was like this: Prove or disprove $char_A (x) = char_{A^{T}}(x)$. Can you point me a step by step for this?

Comment: I figured that this was indeed the goal of your question! However, I cannot think of another way to address it. May I ask what is your definition of the determinant?

Comment: Well, I actually tried a little harder and now solved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to have helped, perhaps I should add that you have to use that $\sigma\mapsto\sigma^{-1}$ is a bijection of $\mathfrak{S}_n$.